# Right Scrolling text

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project to display scrolling text (better "Marquee Text"). 
In my project I am having `Timer1`, `Timer2`, `Button1`, `Button2`, `Label1` and `Label2`.
My object is to display some left scrolling text on `Label1` after `Button1.Click` using `Timer1` and  some right scrolling text on `Label2` after `Button1.Click` using `Timer2`.

I have defined the following codes:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := true;
  Timer2.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Timer2.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Interval := 100;
  Timer2.Interval := 100;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  ScrollingText : string = 'This is left scrolling text ';
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
var
  ScrollPosition: Integer;
begin
  Label1.Caption := ScrollingText;
  for ScrollPosition := 1 to (Length(ScrollingText) - 1) do
    begin
      ScrollingText[ScrollPosition] := Label1.Caption[ScrollPosition + 1];
      ScrollingText[Length(ScrollingText)] := Label1.Caption[1];
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  ScrollingText : string = 'This is right scrolling text ';
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
var
  ScrollPosition: Integer;
begin
  Label2.Caption := ScrollingText;
  for ScrollPosition := (Length(ScrollingText) - 1) to 1 do
    begin
      ScrollingText[ScrollPosition] := Label2.Caption[ScrollPosition - 1];
      ScrollingText[Length(ScrollingText)] := Label2.Caption[1];
    end;
end;

end.
```

My problem is that `Left Scrolling` is happening using `Timer1` but `Right Scrolling` is not happening using `Timer2`.

Comment: Did you try some debugging, e.g., using the debugger or by putting a `ShowMessage('cat')` inside the `for` loop in `Timer2Timer`? [N.b.: you don't have to use "cat" -- any mammal will do.]

Comment: Why are you using writeable typed constants, that oxymoronic and long since deprecated "feature"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop in `Timer2Timer` should run down instead of up:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  ScrollingText : string = 'This is right scrolling text ';
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
var
  ScrollPosition: Integer;
begin
  Label2.Caption := ScrollingText;
  for ScrollPosition := (Length(ScrollingText) - 1) downto 2 do
    begin
      ScrollingText[ScrollPosition] := Label2.Caption[ScrollPosition - 1];
      ScrollingText[1] := Label2.Caption[Length(ScrollingText) - 1];
    end;
end;
```

But I suggest not using writeable const nor using the for loop at all:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  Label2.Caption := 'This is right scrolling text ';
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := Label2.Caption;
  S := S[Length(S)] + Copy(S, 1, Length(S) - 1);
  Label2.Caption := S;
end;
```

Comment: Also in yours, I thought that was by design.

Comment: If right scrolling text means copying the last character and all in front; then would left scrolling not mean copying all last characters plus the first? You should be able finding this out by yourself.

Comment: You don't need that space